# prevent jump to top of page when using Jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-ui-tabs

I have created tabs using jquery, and every time I switch to another tab, it jumps to the top of the page. Is there any way I can prevent this? Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.display_menu_element a').click(function(){
        switch_tabs($(this));
            return false;
    });

    switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));

});

function switch_tabs(obj)
{
    $('.display_tab').hide();
    $('.display_menu_element a').removeClass("selected");
    var id = obj.attr("rel");

    $('#'+id).fadeIn(1200);
    obj.addClass("selected");

    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you click on a "tab", you basically click on a anchor(  tag ), the "href" of the "a" tag needs to be set to the ID of the div to which it is referenced.

Please see the documentation and demo http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

A more in depth information, consider the simple tabs demo, bellow this are the list items that contain the "tabs" on which the user 
clicks, if the user clicks on "Nunc tincidunt", 
the first tab which has "href" attribute set to "#tabs-1", then if div with ID "#tabs-1" is not in view, the browser will scroll there.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li> <!-- a click on this -->
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"> <!-- will point to this -->
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu...</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc..</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante...</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically you need to use the "select" method $( selector ).tabs( "select", index ); to get the desired effect.